# VBScript variable not displaying in document.write

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am writing a HTA to do some basic things, one thing I need is to display free hard drive space. I have this section for the VB Script:

```
Dim FreeHDSpace
Dim test32
test32 = 56

Sub Window_onLoad
    Dim FreeHDSpace
    window.resizeTo 550,700
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set objLogicalDisk = objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'")
    FreeHDSpace = objLogicalDisk.FreeSpace
    FreeHDSpace = FreeHDSpace / 1024
    FreeHDSpace = FreeHDSpace / 1024
    FreeHDSpace = FreeHDSpace / 1024
    FreeHDSpace = Int(FreeHDSpace)
    FreeHDSpace = CStr(FreeHDSpace)
    msgBox(FreeHDSpace)
End Sub
```

And this section in my HTML:

```
<p><font  face="tahoma" color="white" size="4">Hard drive space remaining:</font>
<script type="text/VBScript">
    document.write "<font size='4' face='Tahoma' color='white'>" & FreeHDSpace & " Gb</font>"
</script></P>
```

If i use the variable in test32 instead of FreeHDSpace in the HTML it displays 56. As you can see i  have tried changing it to a string and formating it to a smaller number.

I am seriously stuck, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the variable when the `<script>` element is processed **then** the window's load event fires, triggering the function which gives the variable a value (but that is too late!).

You need to not wait for the load event before giving the variable its value.

Comment: Yes!! I moved them outside the onLoad sub and it is loading perfectly!